# Link C# (C-sharp) and C languages

Tags: c#, c

How can I link `C#` and `C`? I have a game implemented in `C` and I want to aggregate with a library written in `C#`.

Is it possible to convert `C#` code to the `DLL` and then open it in `C`? Or there are an another way to link both languages?

As I understood, the conversation from `C#` to `C` is very difficult and expensive.

Comment: try googling "use managed code from unmanaged", like this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10020/Using-managed-code-in-an-unmanaged-application

Comment: hmm thanks Lanorkin, but I didn't found nothing that explain how to link C and C#, only C++ or C# examples...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to throw away the C code and start from scratch the C# code.

All the libraries that you might be using in C, their equivalent or almost equivalent (even better) are available in C#.

The amount of code in `C`, that cannot be converted directly into `C#` is very high, and you would end up wasting hours and hours making your code work, which you might have completed in a much better way, if you started with scratch in C# in first place.

C is a great language, but drastically less programmer friendly then C# for me :)

Comment: This is not relevant to the question. Also, let's not start (again) the "C++ vs C# / Java / whatever" "topic"

Comment: this is relevant to the problem the user Oleksandr is having. Changing mindset(having a new idea altogether) is sometimes a good solution :)

Comment: Yup, you're right C# is much better then C. But the game (Quake 3 Arena) is implemented in C and there no implementations in other languages.

Comment: Quake 3 Arena?? what??god! i loved that game. anyway. so you must be having a monstrous amount of code, which even presses the fact tht start afresh with c# :)

Comment: C# and C are completely different languages and cannot be compared **at all**. None of them is "better" - both are used for different things.

Comment: @kiril..if you believe that, thn you shd have upvoted me instead :) (that's what i was saying right :) )